# Compatibility of DLL files for Python C extension

Tags: python, c, dll

I'm new to Python, and I'm learning to write C extensions for Python under Windows. Following a tutorial, I successfully compiled my exmaple.dll file using Cygwin.

The dll file seems okay as I can import it and the function of it also works.
Note that this is done using the Python of Cygwin. However, I can't use this dll under my own Python (not the one in Cygwin). I have copied the dll file to the Python search path, though. ImportError was raised.

I'm thinking, is it because the versions of two Python are different?
Cygwin comes with Python 2.7.5, while I use 2.7.6.

Comment: ImportError? How you load dll in Python?

Comment: @mskimm: I'm following Example 22-1, Programming Python, 3rd Ed, Mark Lutz.

Comment: @NorthCat: "import example". I've no problem using the same dll with Python that comes with Cygwin.

Comment: Think it's because Cygwin is a POSIX emulation layer and so binaries compiled against Cygwin libraries make POSIX system calls. Python for Windows (and any other Windows application) does not make POSIX system calls and so is incompatible with libraries (including the one you've made) compiled in Cywgin. I think you need to cross-compile for Windows or compile in [MingW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Comment: @dilbert: dilbert, thanks for your comment. Now I vaguely understand what you mean. Anyway, could you give a simple tutorial (if you can remember) on how to do it in Cygwin? Thank you very much!

Comment: @D-K, its quite simple. Using whatever tutorial you currently are, when it talks about using Cygwin (if it does at all), just use MingW instead. I don't think you can use MingW from Cywgin because of name collisions, so just use the Windows Command Prompt and not the Cygwin shell.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Finally I decided to use Ubuntu, it's simpler to accomplish this.